# Can you drive with an international heavy vehicle license in New York a bus/truck?

Tags: international-travel, driving, driving-licenses, new-york-state

Can you drive with a victoria heavy vehicle license in New York a bus/truck?

Comment: Are you planning to live there and work as a driver, or stay temporarily and use the vehicle as a mobile home? Also, is your licence from Victoria, Australia?

Comment: i'm going for vacation but not for a mobile home

Comment: I don't have an answer to the question, but I'm curious to know why you want to drive a large vehicle on holiday but not as a mobile home.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, if you do not become a resident of New York State, you can drive with your foreign license.  If your foreign license authorizes you to drive the truck then you can use it in New York.  See the Department of Motor Vehicles page on [Driving in New York State](https://dmv.ny.gov/driver-license/drive-new-york-state), which mentions no restrictions on vehicle types.

Note that a regular New York State license allows its bearer to drive trucks up to 26,000 pounds Gross Vehicle Weight Rating; 26,000 pounds is nearly 11,793 kg, so if the truck you're driving does not exceed that, it's likely that a police officer would not pay much attention to the kinds of vehicles you are licensed to drive.

Also note that operating a truck in commercial service would almost certainly cause you to fall afoul of immigration law, and perhaps federal laws governing transportation in interstate commerce, even though your driver's license allows you to operate the vehicle under New York's driver licensing law.